# Context Menu not displaying correct language with PyQt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

When I was trying to create a Qt application using PyQt5, I noticed that QPlainTextEdit standard context menu was being displayed in English , which is not the language of my system (Portuguese), despite its locale was correctly inherited from its parent widget. Is this the expected behavior? If so, how can i add a translation without having to rewrite the functions already present in that context menu (like cut/copy/paste)?

## Example

This program reproduces the behavior described above; it shows a window (thus `textEditor.locale().language()` have the same value as `QLocale.Portuguese`) but  the context menu is shown in english.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QMainWindow()  

    assert(window.locale().language() == QLocale.Portuguese)    
    textEditor = QPlainTextEdit(window)

    assert(textEditor.locale().language() == QLocale.Portuguese)
    window.setCentralWidget(textEditor)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install a [`QTranslator`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtranslator.html) to add the translations for your system locale.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QPlainTextEdit, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale, QTranslator, QLibraryInfo

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Install provided system translations for current locale
    translator = QTranslator()
    translator.load('qt_' + QLocale.system().name(), QLibraryInfo.location(QLibraryInfo.TranslationsPath))
    app.installTranslator(translator)

    window = QMainWindow()

    assert(window.locale().language() == QLocale.Portuguese)
    textEditor = QPlainTextEdit(window)

    assert(textEditor.locale().language() == QLocale.Portuguese)
    window.setCentralWidget(textEditor)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Although `translator.load` returned `True`, which seems to represent that the language was correctly loaded, the context menu remained in english :(

Comment: The assert statements make no sense here: setting a translator does not change the locale.

Comment: @danielbb. It seems that the translation files for portuguese have not been fully ported to qt5 yet. If you try with pyqt4, you will see that the translation works as expected.

Comment: @ekhumoro Oh ok, you're right. I tried loading the polish translation files and it worked. I think I'll skip this translation in my project for now. 
Thanks everyone